# How can I send email with java?

Tags: email, kotlin

I tried to send email with java. But I think the engine to send email is perfect. Then email was not sent.
How can I fix this issue?

I think this issue are seemed to relate with java libs.
This is my sending email code.

```
fun send(email: String, fullName: String?, mailSubject: String, mailText: String, mailHtml: String? = null) {
    // fix_juna 0417_end
    logger.info("Prepare email")
    Transport.send(MimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance(Properties())).apply {
        setFrom(fromAddress)
        logger.info("set from$fromAddress") //fix_juna 0417
        addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress(email, fullName ?: ""))
        logger.info("set email$email, fullname$fullName") //fix_juna 0417
        subject = mailSubject
        setContent(MimeMultipart().apply {
            mailHtml?.also { addBodyPart(MimeBodyPart().apply { setContent(it, "text/html") }) }
            addBodyPart(MimeBodyPart().apply { setContent(mailText, "text/plain") })
        })
    })
}
```

I confirmed this function is ran.
Tips: this code is based on kotlin lanuage.

Why email is not sent and how I set java environment to send email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just send email for free. You need to configure an smtp server (and have one that you can use in the first place), which you have not done in your example because you are using a new instance of `Properties` with nothing set.

Here is a java based guide for setting those properties -> [Sending Emails with Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-email)

As for getting the details of an smtp server, I believe google offers free smtp up to some threshold, but I am sure there are others.

Comment: I have known that to send email using java I must plugin java.mail.. on my local. is this right? And second you mean I can send email free with google? Please share me how to set any environment for sending java programe. Thanks.